# I want to do a UNION with two SELECTS and put inside a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, union

I have this code so far and I would like to get them to UNION into one question but I can't get it to work. I've been trying to do a new Select around cast and everything down to As Nvarchar.

```
DECLARE @tableHTML NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @tableHTML = 
N'<H3>Felaktiga rader</H3>'+
N'<table border="1">'+
N'<tr><th>ID</th>'+
N'<th>Value</th>'+
N'<th>Reason</th>'+

CAST ((SELECT td=ID,'',
td = Value,'',
td = Reason,''

FROM Mail.dbo.CheckMe
WHERE Value = '120' OR Value = '220'
UNION
Mail.dbo.CheckMeTwo
WHERE Value = '120' OR Value = '220'

for XML path ('tr'), TYPE
) as NVARCHAR(MAX))+
N'</table>';

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@recipients = 'ZZXXYY@gmail.com;',
@subject = ' Felaktiga Rader',
@body = @tableHTML,
@body_format = 'HTML';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it this way.

```
FROM (SELECT * FROM Mail.dbo.CheckMe
WHERE Value = '120' OR Value = '220'
UNION
SELECT * FROM Mail.dbo.CheckMeTwo
WHERE Value = '120' OR Value = '220') T
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to select the columns in your second query!!!!

```
SELECT td=ID,'',td = Value,'', td = Reason,''
FROM Mail.dbo.CheckMe
WHERE Value = '120' OR Value = '220'
UNION
SELECT td=ID,'',td = Value,'', td = Reason,''
FROM Mail.dbo.CheckMeTwo
WHERE Value = '120' OR Value = '220'
```

You need a select list for EVERY query in your UNION construction!